# Why is helicity in this context well-defined?

Tags: special-relativity, angular-momentum, dirac-equation, lie-algebra, helicity

I am reading [these notes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1204.0135) on helicity. One of the definitions (see page 5) that is used is the following (here $J^{a}=\bar{\psi} \gamma^{a} \psi$ is the probability current and $K_{a}=\bar{\psi} \gamma_{5} \gamma_{a} \psi$ is the axial current):

**Definition.** Let $\mathbf{J}=J^{a} \gamma_{a}$ and $\mathbf{K}=K_{a} \gamma^{a}$ be the vectors constructed from the vector and axial vector bilinear covariants, respectively. We define helicity $h$ to be the number such that $\mathbf{K}=$ $h \mathbf{J}$.

I don't understand how $h$ is well-defined. Why is it the case that $\mathbf{K}$ is always proportional to $\mathbf{J}$ i.e. $h$ exists (and is real)?

In a similar spirit, if $\psi$ is a flag-pole spinor (see Clifford Algebras and Spinors Lounesto, P., London Mathematical Society Lecture Note Series 239, CUP 1997 for instance) and $S^{a b}=\bar{\psi} i \gamma^{a} \gamma^{b} \psi$ then $\mathbf{S}=\mathbf{J} \mathbf{s}$ for a certain $\mathbf{s}$ such that $\mathbf{J} \cdot \mathbf{s}=0$, $\mathbf{s}^{2}=-1$. Why is it the case that such an $\mathbf{s}$ exists? Any help will be appreciated, thanks.